# Error with generic list argument to Collections.binarySearch

Tags: java, generics

Trying to write a Python style bisect_right in Java, with a generic type for the List argument:

```
import java.util.*;

class Util {

    /* eqv to python's bisect_right. That is: return insertion point, but
    if key is in list, insertion point is to right of it.
    */
    //public static int bisect_right(List<String> list, String x) { //>> type specific
    public static <E> int bisect_right(List<E> list, E x) {
        int idx = Collections.binarySearch(list, x);     

        if (idx >= 0) { // key contained in list
            idx = idx + 1;
        }           
        else {
            idx = -idx -1; 
        }
        return idx;
    }
}
```

The compiler complains about not finding a method matching `Collections.binarySearch`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: E needs to extend Comparable.  See the method signature of the binarySearch method.  P.S. Why not just use binarySearch as-is?  What's the point of mucking up the return value?

Comment: On point: code has to be maintained in both Python and Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `E` needs to be `Comparable<? super E>` for the call to [the `Collections.binarySearch` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch-java.util.List-T-), but you don't have that bound on `E`.

Add that bound to the declaration of `E` on your `bisect_right` method.

```
public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> int bisect_right(List<E> list, E x) {
```

(`<E extends Comparable<E>>` seems to work here too.)

Comment: `<E extends Comparable<E>>` will compile but it won't work for some (many) actual classes.  Use `Comparable<? super E>`.